# Defining Schema for json data in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json as below stored in amazon s3 in json files.

```
{
    "owner": "mindey",
    "ownerId": "4e751a",
    "batch": "test1",
    "mode": "testserve",
    "subType": "self",
    "versionId": "v89.0563",
    "createdDate": "2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z",
    "createdBy": "xyz@nike.com",
    "modifiedBy": "xyz@nike.com",
    "numChanges": 10,
    "progressFlag": true,
    "auditing": {
        "hack": "TBD",
        "facetCd": [
            "652439",
            "A97341"
        ],
        "modelColors": [
            "083y32-058",
            "978t22-456",
            "A097ee-009"
        ],
        "consumersGroup": [
            "25a9874-098a-08nh-4424-90838e"
        ],
        "cnsmrTargets": [
            {
                "id": "7jsfg8734-038h-9825-9784-37768ebe6ba1",
                "type": "self"
            }
        ],
        "modelGroups": [
            {
                "seedIds": [
                    "7kjshf99-754a-gf78-a015",
                    "6d874mq3-23fa-4e76-baad"
                ],
                "exact": true,
                "position": 5
            }
        ],
        "txGroups": [
            {
                "txIds": [
                    "7bw97862-aca7-9873",
                    "5ddfb803-2f11-8763"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "shops": [
            "ue749nt2-acc6-2452",
            "ue749nt2-982y-4286"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I read the files and wanted defined a schema in pyspark to append the data to a table. So I defined my schema as below and read it through a temporary dataframe in pyspark as below. The code didn't error out, however I was looking to get a different result which is also mentioned below

```
sch = StructType([StructField("owner",StringType()), 
        StructField("ownerId",StringType()), 
        StructField("batch",StringType()), 
        StructField("mode",StringType()), 
        StructField("subType",StringType()), 
        StructField("versionId",StringType()), 
        StructField("createdDate",StringType()), 
        StructField("modifiedDate",StringType()), 
        StructField("createdBy",StringType()), 
        StructField("modifiedBy",StringType()), 
        StructField("numChanges",StringType()), 
        StructField("progressFlag",StringType()), 
        StructField("auditing",StringType())])


df_read = spark.read.json(src,schema=sch)
df_read.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
spark.sql("select * from df").show(10,False)

+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|owner |ownerId|batch|mode|subType|versionId|createdDate             |modifiedDate            |createdBy   |modifiedBy  |numChanges|progressFlag|auditing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|mindey|4e751a |test1|null|self   |v89.0563 |2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z|2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z|xyz@nike.com|xyz@nike.com|10        |true        |{"hack":"TBD","facetCd":["652439","A97341"],"modelColors":["083y32-058","978t22-456","A097ee-009"],"consumersGroup":["25a9874-098a-08nh-4424-90838e"],"cnsmrTargets":[{"id":"7jsfg8734-038h-9825-9784-37768ebe6ba1","type":"self"}],"modelGroups":[{"seedIds":["7kjshf99-754a-gf78-a015","6d874mq3-23fa-4e76-baad"],"exact":true,"position":5}],"txGroups":[{"txIds":["7bw97862-aca7-9873","5ddfb803-2f11-8763"]}],"shops":["ue749nt2-acc6-2452","ue749nt2-982y-4286"]}|
+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expect the output to be as below where the nested json is split to different columns appropriately -

```
+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|owner |ownerId|batch|mode|subType|versionId|createdDate             |modifiedDate            |createdBy   |modifiedBy  |numChanges|progressFlag|auditing_hack|auditing_facetCd    |auditing_modelColors                        |auditing_consumersGroup                     |auditing_cnsmrTargets_id                    |auditing_cnsmrTargets_type                  |auditing_modelGroups_seedIds                            |auditing_txGroups_txIds                                 |auditing_txGroups_shops                          |
+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|mindey|4e751a |test1|null|self   |v89.0563 |2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z|2021-12-10T00:41:02.652Z|xyz@nike.com|xyz@nike.com|10        |true        |TBD          |["652439","A97341"] |["083y32-058","978t22-456","A097ee-009"]    |25a9874-098a-08nh-4424-90838e               |7jsfg8734-038h-9825-9784-37768ebe6ba1       |self                                        |["7kjshf99-754a-gf78-a015","6d874mq3-23fa-4e76-baad"]   |["7bw97862-aca7-9873","5ddfb803-2f11-8763"]             |["ue749nt2-acc6-2452","ue749nt2-982y-4286"]}     |
+------+-------+-----+----+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Can someone help me with this result. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You told it `auditing` was a string field.  That's what it delivered.  I think you'll have to introduce substructures to make that work, but how would you handle the lists?  You surely don't want a variable number of columns here.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts - Thanks for your response. I'm not 100% sure about the substructures. Would you mind helping me how it looks. The lists need to be stored as the lists as is in the json data I don't want to explode the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema object should look like this:

```
sch = StructType([
  StructField("owner",StringType()), 
  StructField("ownerId",StringType()), 
  StructField("batch",StringType()), 
  StructField("mode",StringType()), 
  StructField("subType",StringType()), 
  StructField("versionId",StringType()), 
  StructField("createdDate",StringType()), 
  StructField("modifiedDate",StringType()), 
  StructField("createdBy",StringType()), 
  StructField("modifiedBy",StringType()), 
  StructField("numChanges",StringType()), 
  StructField("progressFlag",StringType()), 
  StructField("auditing",StructType([
    StructField('hack', StringType()),
    StructField('facetCd', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('modelColors', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('consumersGroup', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('cnsmrTargets', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('modelGroups', ArrayType(StructType([
      StructField('seedIds', ArrayType(StringType())),
      StructField('exact', StringType()),
      StructField('position', IntegerType()),
    ]))),
    StructField('facetCd', ArrayType(StructType([
      StructField('txIds', ArrayType(StringType())),
    ]))),
    StructField('shops', ArrayType(StringType())),
  ]))
 ]
)
```

Once you apply the schema, you'll get a nested struct for auditing column. Then a combination of select statement and alias can get you the desired column names.

Comment: Hi @crow59 - Thanks for the response. I tried this approach. To my surprise I see the result as all nulls.
Should it follow the order of fields in the json file?

Comment: That happens when there's a mistake in the schema. If the schema doesn't match the JSON structure, the fields are going to be created according to the provided schema, but all values will be null.

Comment: Makes sense . It worked for me with minor changes. Thank you @Crow59