# Json response contains columns and rows seperately

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

My json response contains columns and rows seperately. How to parse following data in pyspark (mapping the columns with rows)

Response is as follows,
Response = "{"columns": [{ "id": { "type": "Numeric", "nullable": false } },{ "name": { "type": "Text", "nullable": false } },{ "description": { "type": "Text", "nullable": true } },{ "last_updated": { "type": "DateTime", "nullable": false } }],
"rows": [[1, "foo", "Lorem ipsum", "2016-10-26T00:09:14Z"],[4, "bar", null, "2013-07-01T13:04:24Z"]]}"

Please help me how to parse it using PySpark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining Schema for json data in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454767/defining-schema-for-json-data-in-pyspark)

Comment: O/P should be like this:

id name description last_updated
1 foo Lorem ipsum 2016-10-26T00:09:14Z
4 bar null 2013-07-01T13:04:24Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your json as a string stored in Response i.e.,

```
Response =  "{"columns": [{ "id": { "type": "Numeric", "nullable": false } },{ "name": { "type": "Text", "nullable": false } },{ "description": { "type": "Text", "nullable": true } },{ "last_updated": { "type": "DateTime", "nullable": false } }], "rows": [[1, "foo", "Lorem ipsum", "2016-10-26T00:09:14Z"],[4, "bar", null, "2013-07-01T13:04:24Z"]]}"
```

- Use `json.loads()` to create a dictionary from this Response(string).

```
import json

data_dict = json.loads(Response)
print(data_dict.keys())

# dict_keys(['columns', 'rows'])
```

- Retrieve row data (data for dataframe) and column data (create schema for dataframe) as shown below:

```
rows = data_dict['rows'] #input data for creating dataframe
print(rows)
#[[1, 'foo', 'Lorem ipsum', '2016-10-26T00:09:14Z'], [4, 'bar', None, '2013-07-01T13:04:24Z']]

cols = data_dict['columns']
l = [i for column in cols for i in column.items()]

#schema_str to create a schema (as a string) using response column data
schema_str = "StructType(["

convert = [] 
#list of columns that should be as DateTime. 
#First create dataframe as StringType column for these and then convert each column..
#in convert (list) to TimestampType.

for c in l:

    #column name
    col_name = c[0]   
    
    #column type
    if(c[1]['type'] =='Numeric'):
        col_type = 'IntegerType()'
    elif(c[1]['type'] == 'Text'):
        col_type = 'StringType()'
    elif(c[1]['type'] == 'DateTime'):
        #converting datetime type to StringType, to later convert to TimestampType
        col_type = 'StringType()'
        convert.append(col_name) #appending columns to be converted to a list
    
    #if column is nullable or not
    col_nullable = c[1]['nullable']
    
    
    schema_str = schema_str+f'StructField("{col_name}",{col_type},{col_nullable}),'
    
schema_str = schema_str[:-1] + '])'

print(schema_str)
#StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType(),False),StructField("name",StringType(),False),StructField("description",StringType(),True),StructField("last_updated",StringType(),False)])
```

- Now use row data and above schema(string) to create dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rows, schema=eval(schema_str))
df.show()
df.printSchema()

#output

+---+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id|name|description|        last_updated|
+---+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1| foo|Lorem ipsum|2016-10-26T00:09:14Z|
|  4| bar|       null|2013-07-01T13:04:24Z|
+---+----+-----------+--------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_updated: string (nullable = false)
```

- Convert the columns that need to be type casted to `TimestampType()`

```
for to_be_converted in convert:
    df = df.withColumn(to_be_converted, to_timestamp(to_be_converted).cast(TimestampType()))
df.show()
df.printSchema()

#output

+---+----+-----------+-------------------+
| id|name|description|       last_updated|
+---+----+-----------+-------------------+
|  1| foo|Lorem ipsum|2016-10-26 00:09:14|
|  4| bar|       null|2013-07-01 13:04:24|
+---+----+-----------+-------------------+


root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_updated: timestamp (nullable = true)
```